# While getting PDF locally via rotativa why can't I download PDF via online?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

When I'm running my code locally I am able to get the PDF via Rotativa but if I do this online it throws me an error.

I've tried adding `msvcp120.dll`, `msvcr120.dll` server side and local on my machine as well.

This is how I am getting my pdf:

```
       var model = new GrievanceDetailsReportModel()
        {
            getGrievanceDetailsReport = list
        };


        return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("DetailsReportPdf", model)
        {
            FileName = "DetailsReport.pdf",

        };
```

The error says:

> An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: Please can you add more information. It would be good to know the whole error. If you can't see it in your logs, it might be in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Explain what/how you try to get it via "online". Add traceback information if available on the error. End of Triage-Review > requires editing.

Comment: did you copy the rotativa folder to the server.

Comment: yes i uploaded published file uxmaan

Comment: @New Bee 1 use roll-backs if they really don't make sense. User k.k. added styling for your error, which makes sense for clarity reasons and convention. My proposed edit got trashed due it. See the comment why I posted the edit. However, its now in peer-review and if accepted this comment can be removed).